# SVG color-shadow filter fails when built with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, svg, svg-filters

I created a drop-shadow for an SVG image, which works fine using pure SVG (see [**a live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9dMWz/)):

```svg
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
            <defs>
                <filter id="drop">
                    <feComponenttransfer result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha">
                        <feFuncA type="linear" />
                        <feFuncR type="discrete" tablevalues="1" />
                        <feFuncG type="discrete" />
                        <feFuncB type="discrete" />
                    </feComponentTransfer>
                    <feOffset result="shadow" dx="67" dy="0" in="offOut" />
                    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="8" result="blurOut" in="shadow" />
                    <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
                </filter>
            </defs>
            <g>
                <g filter="url(#drop)">
                    <image x="10" y="100" width="440" height="60" xlink:href="/images/pulpit.jpg"
                    preserveAspectRatio="defer"></image>
                </g>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here the image is created with a red shadow, as expected, but than I try to create and modify the SVG via JavaScript, using the following code (see [**a live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7uJU7/)):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <body>
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="sv">
            <rect width="90" height="90" stroke="green" stroke-width="3" fill="rgba(255,25,8,1)"
            />
            <g id="gr">
                <image x="10" y="100" width="440" height="60" xlink:href="/images/pulpit.jpg"
                preserveAspectRatio="defer"></image>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
    <script>
        var feoffset = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feOffset");
        var feGaussianBlur = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feGaussianBlur");
        var filter = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "filter");
        var definition = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "defs");

        filter.setAttribute("id", "fPicture5");
        filter.setAttribute("filterUnits", "userSpaceOnUse");
        feoffset.setAttribute("result", "shadow");
        feoffset.setAttribute("in", "offOut");

        feoffset.setAttribute("dx", "67");
        feoffset.setAttribute("dy", "0");

        feGaussianBlur.setAttribute("result", "blurOut");
        feGaussianBlur.setAttribute("in", "shadow");
        feGaussianBlur.setAttribute("stdDeviation", "8");

        var feBlend = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feBlend");
        var feCTransfer = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feComponentTransfer");

        var feFuncR = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feFuncR");
        var feFuncG = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feFuncG");
        var feFuncB = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "feFuncB");

        feCTransfer.setAttribute("in", "SourceAlpha");
        feCTransfer.setAttribute("result", "offOut");

        feBlend.setAttribute("in", "SourceGraphic");
        feBlend.setAttribute("in2", "blurOut");
        feBlend.setAttribute("mode", "normal");

        feFuncR.setAttribute("type", "discrete");
        feFuncG.setAttribute("type", "discrete");
        feFuncB.setAttribute("type", "discrete");

        feFuncR.setAttribute("tablevalues", "1");
        feFuncG.setAttribute("tablevalues", "0");
        feFuncB.setAttribute("tablevalues", "0");

        feCTransfer.appendChild(feFuncR);
        feCTransfer.appendChild(feFuncG);
        feCTransfer.appendChild(feFuncB);

        filter.appendChild(feCTransfer);
        filter.appendChild(feoffset);
        filter.appendChild(feGaussianBlur);
        filter.appendChild(feBlend);

        definition.appendChild(filter);
        document.getElementById("sv").appendChild(definition);
        document.getElementById("gr").setAttribute("filter", "url(#fPicture5)");
    </script>

</html>
```

The result is the image is successfully created, but the shadow is black.

I can't find a way around to make it red as intended, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly fine on Firefox [once I replace the image](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/5tN84/) with one that actually exists e.g. the one in the other fiddle:

```
<image x="10" y="100" width="440" height="60" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/100/80"
preserveAspectRatio="defer"></image>
```

If you are using some other UA and it doesn't work then perhaps you should raise a bug on whatever bug tracker it uses.

Did you realise you're also missing the feFuncA feComponentTransfer child in the second fiddle?

Comment: No, the shadow should be red, not black as in the first fiddle

Comment: They are both black on Firefox.

Comment: I want to make the second fiddle for the shadow to become red, strangely, the first fiddle's shadow is red on Chrome, while it's black on firefox(tested), and the second fiddle is black on both browser

Comment: Firefox and Opera display black. Presumably you've found a Chrome bug.

Comment: so then I can't change the black shadow into a different color? I can't use feColorMatrix with SourceGraphic because it will reflect the image as well

Comment: That would seem to be a new and different question :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this? http://jsfiddle.net/WvYpS/

Replaces the `feComponentTransfer` with an `feColorMatrix`:

```
<feColorMatrix type="matrix" 
 values="0 0 0 1 0  
         0 0 0 0 0 
         0 0 0 0 0 
         0 0 0 1 0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your feFuncR tableValues to "1 1" - now it's fixed in Firefox.

```
<feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="1 1" />
```

There was a bug in Firefox that didn't treat discrete tableValues with a single value correctly that has since been fixed in edge.